# Creating multiple symlinks from a string

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, bash-scripting, sh

I have the following script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

test="../t1,../t2,../t3"

ln -sf "{${test}}" .
```

Above this directory consists of 3 directories:

```
../
├── script
│   └── test.sh
├── t1
├── t2
└── t3
```

The problem I'm having with my code is that it creates a symlink:

```
t3} -> {../t1,../t2,../t3}
```

What I expect to see is:

```
t1 -> ../t1
t2 -> ../t2
t3 -> ../t3
```

I think the problem is how I am escaping around the outer set of `{`, `}` but I can't seem to get that working.

Comment: `ln -sf {"$test"} .` still produces `t3} -> {../t1,../t2,../t3}`

Comment: `test="../t1 ../t2 ../t3"; ln -s $test .` isn't correct either, that produces `t3 -> '../t1 ../t2 ../t3'`

Comment: My bad, you're right, removing the substituting the comma for space and removing the double globbing quotes does indeed work. It also works in /bin/sh too. I was using bash 5.1.8(1).

Comment: your origin script works if you add prefix `eval` before `ln`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess array is what you were looking for

```
test=(../t1 ../t2 ../t3)
ln -s "${test[@]}" .
```

This won't break on whitespaces in array members

```
test=("../t 1" "../t 2" "../t 3")
ln -s "${test[@]}" .
```

Comment: An array probably is the safest answer, and as the question specified bash then I think I'll make this the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

`echo ${test} | awk -F, '{for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) print "ln -s", $i}' | /bin/bash`

Would be easier without the , separator in the string. Question title should be "Creating *multiple* symlinks from a string"

Comment: Yes you're right, that is a better subject, so I've changed it so hopefully people will find it easier. As for the awk answer, this isn't a bad idea if one wanted to keep the script POSIX sh compatible. As it happens I can make the separator anything I like as this input came from jq `sym_links=$(jq -r  --argjson j $i '.data[$j].sym_links | join(" ")' data.json)`

Comment: @dogman Personally, I *try* to keep most of my shell scripts POSIX sh compatible. I've found that makes portability easier, although the ubiquity of Linux these days makes that somewhat moot.

Comment: As do I as, sometimes I might run these on a distribution like Alpine Linux where I have busybox, ie `/bin/ash`.